# Combining \ and / in a path

Tags: c#, path

I was reading [this MDSN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/how-to-write-object-data-to-an-xml-file) on writing Objects to XML files, and there is a part where they create a path with both forward and backward slashes:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "//SerializationOverview.xml";
```

Why do they do this? I would have thought `Path.Combine` would be preferred, but instead, the first portion results in a path with backslashes (`C:\...\`) and they intentionally append a forward-slashed file name.
Is there a reason for doing this? I'm assuming it will work no matter what since .NET seems to be pretty smart about this sort of thing, but does it even matter in any way?

Comment: My guess is that's a typo.

Comment: single `'\'` back slashes in C# language are seen as escape characters therefore you need to use double backslashes `"\\"`  or the literal sign `@"c:\somepath\somepath\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet appears to be demonstrating portable code.

Forward slash is a legal path separator on almost every operating system.  Backslash is usable on Win32 (including mixed with forward slash)... and pretty much nowhere else.  .NET does run on operating systems where backslash is not a legal separator.

That said, forward slash is not ideal for portability.  `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` would be better, and (as you already observed) `Path.Combine()` would be best of all.

Doubling the forward slash does appear to be a typo.  Backslashes are often doubled, to prevent interpretation as an escape character, but this is neither necessary nor desirable with forward slashes.

---

Note: Support for forward slash, as a compatibility feature, is provided in the Win32 layer.  You can't arbitrarily use forward slashes in paths passed to kernel functions, and I wouldn't try it when using the `\\?\` prefix (prevent canonicalization) either.

Answer (score 0):

I think its just an error in typing, I've tried the code and it simply creates the file SerializationOverview.xml under my Documents folder.